# Prove that $F(p)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}dt$ is $\mathcal C^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,+\infty [\to \mathbb R$ continuous and non-negative s.t. $$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}dt$$ exist for all $p$. $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. Define $F:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ by $$F(p)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}dt.$$

Show that $F\in \mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)$.

---

$$|F(p+h)-F(p)|\leq \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}|1-e^{-ht}|dt.$$

I'm trying to upper bound $|1-e^{-ht}|$ to apply DCT, but I have problem. I know that if $h>0$ then $$e^{-ht}-1=O(ht),$$ and thus $$|e^{-ht}-1|\leq C|ht|,$$
and thus if we take $|h|\leq 1$, then $|1-e^{-ht}|\leq Ct.$ If $p>0$ then $tf(t)e^{-pt}$ is integrable, and thus the claim follow with DCT.

Q1) When $p<0$ how I can conclude ?

Q2), When $h<0$ how can I do ?

Q3) When I write $e^{-ht}-1=O(ht)$, is it in fact $e^{-ht}-1=O(h) $ ?

Comment: This is the definition of the Laplace Transform, only with $p$ instead of the more usual $s$. Where does $p$ live? That is, is $p\in\mathbb{C}$ or $p\in\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister: As written : $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $F(p)=...$. -Peter, for Q3), the constant depend on $t$, and thus $e^{-ht}-1=O_t(h)$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: $p\in\mathbb R$

Comment: @Surb: And if I write $e^{-ht}-1+ht=o(ht)$ is it $e^{-ht}-1+ht=o(h)$ or still $e^{-ht}-1+ht=o_t(h)$ ?

Comment: @Peter: Are you needing to show that $F$ is $C^1$ or $C^2?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister: Since I have an example for the continuity, I can continue. Tks

Comment: @AdrianKeister: I in fact ask the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856790/compute-lim-h-to-0fte-pt-left-frace-ht-1h-rightdt) for the derivability. If you have an idea...

Answer (score 0):

Q1)  You have that $$tf(t)e^{-pt}\leq tf(t)e^{-at}=te^{-t}f(t)e^{-(p-1)t}.$$
Now $t\longmapsto f(t)e^{-(p-1)t}$ is integrable and $t\longmapsto te^{-t}$ is also integrable. Therefore $$t\longmapsto tf(t)e^{-pt}$$
is integrable.

Q2) You also have $$e^{-ht}-1=O(ht),$$
when $h<0$. In particular, if $h<0$, then $|e^{-ht}-1|\leq 2|ht|.$