# Compute $\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|dt.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,\infty [\to \mathbb R$ a non negative function s.t. $f(t)e^{-pt}$ is integrable for all $p\in\mathbb R$. Set $$F(p)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}dt.$$
Compute $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(p+h)-F(p)}{h}.$$

---

### **First try**

I have that $$\left|\frac{F(p+h)-F(p)}{h}\right|\leq\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|dt.$$

I want to prove that  $$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|dt=\int_0^\infty \lim_{h\to 0}f(t)e^{-pt}\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|dt.$$

I have that $$e^{-x}=1+O(x),$$
i.e. there is $C>0$ and $\delta>0$ s.t. $$|e^{-x}-1|\leq C|x|,$$
and thus, if $|ht|\leq \delta$, we have that 
$$\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|\leq Ct,$$
i.e. if $|h|\leq \frac{\delta}{t}$ ,
$$\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|\leq Ct\tag{E}$$

I know that if I would have $(E)$ for all $|h|\leq \delta$ for a certain $\delta$, then I can conclude. But since I have $E$ only for $|h|\leq \frac{\delta}{t}$ (i.e. I can't get a uniform upper bound for $h$), I suppose that it's a problem. So, how can I conclude ?

---

### **Second try**

I set $g(t,p)=f(t)e^{-pt}$
$$\int_0^\infty g(t,p)\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|dt=\int_{0}^\infty g(t,p)\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{-ht}\right|dt.$$

I would say that since $e^{-ht}=1-ht+o(h)$ when $h\to 0$, that $$\int_{0}^\infty g(t,p)\left(\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{-ht}\right)dt=\int_{0}^\infty g(t,p)(1+o(h))dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty tg(t,p)dt+o(h)\int_0^\infty g(t,p)dt\underset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow } \int_0^\infty g(t,p)dt,$$

But I really have doubt with all what I'm doing here. First of all, I'm not convinced with $$e^{-ht}=1-ht+o(h),$$
since the $o(h)$ should have a dependence on $t$. In fact $$e^{-ht}=1-ht+o_t(h),$$ looks mor correct, and thus, I can't take of the $o_t(h)$ of the integral since it depend on $t$. So I would say : there is $\varepsilon:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $$e^{x}=1+x+x\varepsilon(x),$$
where $\lim_{x\to 0}\varepsilon(x)=0.$ Now $$e^{-ht}=1-ht+ht\varepsilon(ht),$$
and thus $$\int_{0}^\infty g(t,p)\left(\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{-ht}\right)dt=\int_0^\infty  g(t,p)(1+th\varepsilon(th))dt=\int_0^\infty 
 g(t,p)dt+h\int_0^\infty g(t,p)\varepsilon(th)dt.$$
Now, I have to compute $$\lim_{h\to 0}h\int_0^\infty tg(t,p)\varepsilon(ht)dt.$$
We have $\lim_{h\to 0}\varepsilon(ht)=0$ for all $t$. May be There is $\delta>0$ and $M>0$ (independent of $t$) s.t. $|\varepsilon(xt)|\leq M$, and thus I would be done, but unfortunately, the best I can get is : if $t>0$ is fixed, there is $\delta=\delta_t>0$ s.t. $$|h|\leq \delta_t \implies |\varepsilon(xt)|\leq 1,$$
and thus the $\delta$ still depend on $t$.

Comment: +1 for the effort.

Comment: If it's true for all $p\in \mathbb R ,$ why not just write $e^{pt}?$ And why do you have absolute values in the title but not in the statement of the problem?

Comment: Also, you have $h\to 0$ in the title and $h\to \infty $ in the statement. Which is it?

Comment: @zhw.: I corrected it. For $e^{-pt}$, sorry it's the statement of my exercise... But it doesn't change anything... Put $p$ instead of $-p$ if you prefer.

Comment: Why the downvote ? Could the person who downvoted explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$\kappa:p\longmapsto e^{-pt}$$ is $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$.

Let $p\in \mathbb R$ and take $|h|\leq 1$. Using MVT, there is $|c_h|\leq |h|$ s.t. $$|e^{-(p+h)t}-e^{-pt}|\leq \kappa'(p+c_h)h=e^{-pt}e^{-c_ht}h\leq e^te^{-pt}h,$$
since $|c_h|\leq 1$. 
Finally, $$0\leq f(t)e^{-pt}\left|\frac{e^{-ht}-1}{h}\right|\leq f(t)e^{-pt}e^t=f(t)e^{(1-p)t},$$
that is integrable. Therefore, you can apply DCT.

Comment: What does DCT means?

Comment: @TomDomenge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem